# Proof verification : risk free rate

Tags: interest-rates, differential-equations, proof

I want to prove that
$$r_t = \theta + (r_0 -\theta)e^{-kt}$$
satisfies $$dr_t = k(\theta-r_t)dt, \ r(0) = r_0$$
I have
\begin{split}\frac{1}{\theta - r_t} dr_t = kdt \Rightarrow & \int_0^t \frac{1}{\theta - r_s} dr_s = \int_0^t kds\\
\Rightarrow &- \ln|\theta - r_s|\big\lvert_0^t = ks\big\lvert_0^t\\
\Rightarrow &-\ln|\theta - r_t| + \ln|\theta - r_0| = kt\\
\Rightarrow &\ln|\theta - r_t| - \ln|\theta - r_0| = -kt\\
\Rightarrow &\ln\left|\frac{\theta - r_t}{\theta - r_0}\right|= -kt\\
\Rightarrow &\frac{r_t - \theta}{r_0-\theta} = e^{-kt}\\
\Rightarrow & r_t = \theta + (r_0 -\theta)e^{-kt}
\end{split}
Is this the way to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: Why don’t you just differentiate your first equation?

Comment: I would say you proved that the solution of the differential equation is $r_t$ (which is quite harder), rather than proved that $r$ **satisfies** the differential equation (which is easier: just compute the derivatives and check)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:
$$r(t):=\theta+(r_0-\theta)e^{-kt}\tag{1}$$
Then:
$$r^\prime(t)=-k(r_0-\theta)e^{-kt}\tag{2}$$
which is clearly equal to:
$$k(\theta-r(t))\tag{3}$$
based on $(1)$.